C++ : Polymorphism does not work with reference
I have an application with 2 kinds of products: simple products (Produit, "products") and products that have their own recipe (ProduitCuisine, "prepared food").
A recipe is a collection of Ingredients (made of a product and a quantity).
In the main, I am adding products to make a "glaçage" and then adding products to make a "glaçage parfumé", which is itself made of a collection of products and a "ProduitCuisine" (defined before, thus a mix between products and prepared food).
I want my main to print the products I am adding and whenever the product is a ProduitCuisine (prepared food) I want my main to print its entire recipe.
I suppose it should work with the function toString() (equivalent to my "print"), which should be polymorphic. Is it correct? And, how should I define it?
Here is my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

/*****************************************************
  * Compléter le code à partir d'ici
 *****************************************************/
#include <string>
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------- Classe Produit  ---------------------------
class Produit {

    public:
        Produit(string nom, string unite);
        string getNom() const {return nom;}
        string getUnite() const {return unite;}
        virtual string toString() const {return nom;}

    protected:
        string nom;
        string unite;
};

Produit::Produit(string nom, string unite="") : nom(nom), unite(unite) {}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------- Classe Ingredient  ------------------------
class Ingredient {
    
    public: 
        Ingredient(const Produit& produit, double quantite); 
        Produit getProduit() const& {return produit;}
        double getQuantite() const {return quantite;}
        string descriptionAdaptee() const;
    
    protected:
        Produit produit;
        double quantite;

};

Ingredient::Ingredient(const Produit& produit, double quantite) : produit(produit), quantite(quantite) {}

string Ingredient::descriptionAdaptee() const{
    string s1, s2, s3;
    s1 = to_string(quantite);
    s2 = " ";
    s3 = " de ";
    
    if(produit.getUnite()!="") {
        return " " + s1 + s2 + produit.getUnite() + s3 + produit.toString();
    } else {
        return " " + s1 + produit.getUnite() + s3 + produit.toString();
    }

}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------- Classe Recette  ---------------------------
class Recette {
    
    public:
        Recette(string nom, double nbFois_); 
        void ajouter(const Produit& p, double quantite);
        string toString() const;
    
    protected:
        string nom;
        double nbFois_;
        vector<Ingredient> ingredients;

};

Recette::Recette(string nom, double nbFois_=1) : nom(nom), nbFois_(nbFois_) {}

void Recette::ajouter(const Produit& p, double quantite) {
    Ingredient ingredient(p, nbFois_ * quantite);
    ingredients.push_back(ingredient);  

}

string Recette::toString() const {
    string descriptionadaptee;
    cout << "Recette \"" << nom << "\" x " << nbFois_ << ":" << endl;
    
    for(size_t i(0); i<ingredients.size(); ++i) {
        
        if(i==ingredients.size()-1) {
            descriptionadaptee += to_string(i+1) + "." + ingredients[i].descriptionAdaptee();
        } else {
            descriptionadaptee += to_string(i+1) + "." + ingredients[i].descriptionAdaptee() + "\n";
        }   
    }
    return descriptionadaptee;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------- Classe ProduitCuisine  --------------------
class ProduitCuisine : public Produit {
    
    public:
        ProduitCuisine(string nom, string unite="portion(s)") : Produit(nom, unite), recette(nom) {}
        void ajouterARecette(const Produit& produit, double quantite);
        
        const ProduitCuisine* adapter(double n) override {
            ProduitCuisine* nouveau_produit = new ProduitCuisine(nom);
            nouveau_produit->recette.adapter(n);
            return nouveau_produit;
        }
        
        string toString() const override;
    
    protected:
        Recette recette;
};

void ProduitCuisine::ajouterARecette(const Produit& produit, double quantite) {
    recette.ajouter(produit, quantite);
}

string ProduitCuisine::toString() const {
    
    string resultat;
    
    resultat = nom + "\n" + recette.toString();
    
    return resultat;
}

 int main() { 
  Produit oeufs("oeufs");
  Produit farine("farine", "grammes");
  Produit beurre("beurre", "grammes");
  Produit sucreGlace("sucre glace", "grammes");
  Produit chocolatNoir("chocolat noir", "grammes");
  Produit amandesMoulues("amandes moulues", "grammes");
  Produit extraitAmandes("extrait d'amandes", "gouttes");

  ProduitCuisine glacage("glaçage au chocolat");
  // recette pour une portion de glaçage:
  glacage.ajouterARecette(chocolatNoir, 200);
  glacage.ajouterARecette(beurre, 25);
  glacage.ajouterARecette(sucreGlace, 100);
  cout << glacage.toString() << endl;

  ProduitCuisine glacageParfume("glaçage au chocolat parfumé");
  // besoin de 1 portions de glaçage au chocolat et de 2 gouttes
  // d'extrait d'amandes pour 1 portion de glaçage parfumé

  glacageParfume.ajouterARecette(extraitAmandes, 2);
  glacageParfume.ajouterARecette(glacage, 1);
  cout << glacageParfume.toString() << endl;

return 0;
}


Whereas current code might be complete, it is not minimal. Try to remove extra stuff unneeded. BTW, your code doesn't compile Demo.

Once compilation fixed, it seems to work Demo

Sounds as if you want a Composite.

I think you do not understand polymorphism. Firstly the code does correctly define toString as polymorphic, but secondly, given the main function you have, your code would work exactly the same if toString was not polymorphic. In C++ polymorphism requires pointers (or references) and there are no pointers in your main function.

I want my main to print the products I am adding -- Where is your print function?  I don't see it, and my French is rusty.

"I want my main to [...]" -- How is what you want different from what it does? A comparison of expected and actual output is often a good way to present this.
